# rails ajax-datatables-rails empty table

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im kinda new to web development so sorry if I'm missing something obvious, usually I dig until I find an answer but this time I had no luck. I'm trying to integrate **ajax-datatables-rails** with **Rails 4.2.6** and **bootstrap 3** but when I load the page I get an empty table, I was following the tutorials but I don't seem to find something more recent than the rails cast or something that clues me where I'm wrong.

**view (index.html.erb)**

```
<table id="paciente-table" data-source="<%= pacientes_path(format: :json) %>">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Paterno</th>
  <th>Materno</th>
  <th>Nombre</th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**pacientes_datatables.rb**

```
include AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions::Kaminari

class PacientesDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end


  def sortable_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    @sortable_columns ||= %w('paciente.nombre', 'paciente.paterno',     'paciente.materno')
  end

  def searchable_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
  @searchable_columns ||= %w('paciente.nombre', 'paciente.paterno', 'paciente.materno')
  end

  private

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      [
        record.nombre,
        record.paterno,
        record.materno
      ]
    end
  end

 def get_raw_records
    Paciente.all
  end

 # ==== Insert 'presenter'-like methods below if necessary
end
```

**pacientes_controller.rb**

```
 def index
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json { render json: PacientesDatatable.new(view_context) }
  end
 end
```

**pacientes.js.coffeescript**

```
$ ->
  $('#paciente-table').dataTable
    processing: false
    serverSide: true
    ajax: $('#paciente-table').data('source')
    pagingType: 'full_numbers'
```

I followed the ajax-datatables-rails tutorials on setting up with a mysql db

Comment: We have no way to debug this for you, and I'm sorry to say but tutorials aren't really useful for learning how to debug.  You're going to have to figure out whether or not the issue is server-side or client-side, and then narrow it down from there.  Learn to bisect issues and you will likely solve this for yourself.  Why is the table empty?  Did you get any data from the server?  Did your JavaScript even run?  Did your CoffeeScript even get converted to JavaScript correctly?  Is the markup not what's expected?  Who knows... you need to narrow this down with your developer tools.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I went down another road and got what I wanted working so I guess this ends here...

Comment: hey, try to use branch 0-4 and here is working example - https://github.com/ajahongir/ajax-datatables-rails-v-0-4-0-how-to
and some docs http://ajahongir.github.io/ajax-datatables-rails/